# Operations are repeated in MVVM view model when try execute a different operation in remote system

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing an debugging application which uses WMI protocol to communicate with remote system. This application is developed in .NET 4.5 framework and uses MVVM pattern. In my case, MainViewModel is bound with MainView.xaml and the rest of the Views are also bound with repective ViewModels using DataTemplate in the MainView.xaml file.

Problem : Let me define the problem with an example.

1. Assume there is ManagementView.xaml which is having three buttons (start, stop, restart).
2. When user clicks on a button (start) , the ManagementViewModel.cs will try to use a ManagementScope object that is already been connected.
3. After the first click, the user wants to restart. Then he will click restart button. Again ManagementViewModel.cs will use the existing ManagementScope to connect with the remote system to execute.
4. But the problem is, it is first executing the start operation, then the restart operation is executing. Again if you click another button, these two operations are repeated, then the required operation is executed.

How to resolve this issue ?

It seems like the operations performed are stored in queue, then when user clicks on a new button, all the previous operations are repeated. After that the required operation is performed.

I expect only the particular operation should be executed when user clicks on a button. But the required operation executed after repeating the previous operations. I am still confused, whether the viewModel is creating this problem or is it because of I am using a Connected ManagementScope object for doing the operations.

`enter code here`

```
private void UpdateAgentStatus()
{
logger.Info("Updating the Agent current status asynchronous method");
//Running process in asynchronous mode
backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_UpdateAgentStatus;
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BackgroundWorker_UpdateAgentStatus(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
logger.Info("Setting the BusyIndicator as true to update agent status");
//Setting the loading visible
BusyContent = "Refreshing ...";
IsBusy = true;
//Performing other actions using ManagementScope object
}

private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
logger.Info("Disabling the BusyIndicator after the process completion");
IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: 1) Could you post any relevant code? 2) Do you set proper `CanExecute` result? 3) Do you use any sort of busy indicator to prevent user to trigger another action?

Comment: Yes. I am using BusyIndicator to prevent user from executing more than one operation. I am using Prism library to publish and subscribe for events. DelegateCommands are used to execute the button clicks.

Comment: As you can see that the UpdateAgentStatus method will be called when user clicks on a button.